# If $f(x,t) : \mathbb{T}^3 \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ solves the periodic heat equation and $f(x,0)=0$, is it true that $f$ is identically zero?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\mathbb{T}^3 : = (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$ be the $3$-dimensional torus and $f(x,t) : \mathbb{T}^3 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. $f$ is smooth on $\mathbb{T}^3 \times (0,\infty)$.
2. $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{T}^3$
3. $\partial_t f-\Delta_x f=0$ on $\mathbb{T}^3 \times (0,\infty)$.

Then, "without" a priori assumption of continuity for $f(x,t)$ at $t=0$, can we still conclude that $f(x,t)=0$ for "all" $(x,t) \in \mathbb{T}^3 \times [0,\infty)$?

I guess this is true, but cannot prove / disprove my conjecture rigorously.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: For $1.$ you can just say $f$ is smooth. I prefer to see functions distinguished from their values, $f(x,t)$ is a value

Comment: Oh, ok I have revised that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can take any nonzero solution $g:\Bbb T^3\times(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ and simply extend it by zero to $f:\Bbb T^3\times[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ without violating any conditions. So this should be false, assuming nonzero solutions to $(1)$ and $(3)$ exist

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for your comment. My full question is in the following link, in fact.. Could you please help me with it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746940/space-time-convolution-with-the-heat-kernel-still-continuous

Comment: I'll vote but that kind of analysis is outside of my experience